# Authentication to vimeo through API

Tags: ios, vimeo

I have few video samples on vimeo and i want to view these videos in ios app. I read many times vimeo Api documentation and i registered my apps but i was unable to create token access and secret key. I also followed below vimeo instruction never been redirected to "OAuth 2" page or have not seen any OAuth 2 tab at all.

**Authentication in the new API.**

> Create your API app Go to https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/new, fill out the necessary information and click “Create App”. You will be redirected to your app details page; click the “OAuth 2” tab to find the following authentication information: Client ID - A unique identifier for your application Client Secret - A secret identifier for your application, this should never be shared with anyone Client Access Token - A token that allows your app to make unauthenticated requests User Access Token - A token that allows you to make API requests authenticated as yourself (the app owner)"

Can someone please help me with how can i create access token and other secret keys then access from ios app.

Thank you

Comment: Where did you find these docs? The oauth2 tab is old, and not referenced on vimeo.com. The new tab is "Authentication"

Answer (score 1):

The correct tab is "Authentication". This gives you your client id, client secret, and a way to manually generate access tokens for your own account.

If you want to connect to other users accounts, you can use Vimeo's [VIMNetworking library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimnetworking)

Comment: I have downloaded VIMNetworking but not exactly sure how to connect with VIMNetworking ? Examples please?

Comment: Do you still need help connecting? The readme has quite a few examples